# MIPS Assembly recursive binary search tree not setting left and right child nodes

Tags: recursion, assembly, binary-search-tree, mips

I implemented a recursive binary search tree and am having a hard time adding in nodes once I set the root. Conceptually, I know what I need to do and drew out a quick example (I apologize if the picture came out weird). The $a0 register will have the address of a variable that contains the pointer to the root node of the tree (i.e., a pointer to a pointer to the root node). The $a1 register is the number to add to the tree. So walking through the example, at the very beginning $a0 will point to ptr_root, which will point to the newly created root node. A node structure contains the value of the current node (offset 0), a pointer to the left child (offset 4), and a pointer to the right child (offset 8). When you look at the code, you'll see a few lines where I use a routine called allocate_mem, which initializes the structure with those word length fields. Now, once build_tree runs again for another number, if there is a root, it will recurse to the right or left. **What it should be doing is update $a0 so that it now points to the left/right child of the current node. This is where I am having trouble.** My program now doesn't run, because I made changes that have me use nonexistent memory. However, when it did run, it would only display the root node. I suspect that I was either loading the value of the left (instead of the pointer) or not updating the pointer. What's been really throwing me off is how I can get to the left or right child and of course update the pointer. Any ideas?

```
        .globl  allocate_mem
        .globl  ptr_root

#
# Name:         build_tree
#
# Description:  creates a new node with the provided number, and then insert
#               this new node in the proper position in the binary search
#               tree, updating whatever pointer is necessary.
#
# Arguments:    a0 the address of the variable that contains the pointer to
#               the root node of the tree (i.e., a pointer to a pointer to
#               the root node).
#               a1 the number to be inserted into the tree
#
build_tree:

        addi    $sp,$sp,-8
        sw      $ra, 4($sp)
        sw      $s0, 0($sp)

        beq     $a0, $zero, new_root

        slt     $t1, $a1, $s0
        bne     $t1, $zero, go_left

#        lw      $s0, 0($a0)
        la      $s0, 0($a0)
        la      $t5, 8($s0)
        move    $a0, $t5
        jal     build_tree

new_root:

        li      $a0, 3
        jal     allocate_mem

        la      $t3, ptr_root
        lw      $t4, 0($t3)

        sw      $a1, 0($v0)
        sw      $zero, 4($v0)
        sw      $zero, 8($v0)

        sw      $v0, 0($t3)
        j       finished

go_left:

#        lw      $s0, 0($a0)
        la      $s0, 0($a0)
        la      $t5, 4($s0)
        move    $a0, $t5
        jal     build_tree

finished:

        lw      $ra, 4($sp)
        lw      $s0, 0($sp)
        addi    $sp,$sp,8
        jr      $ra
```

[image]

Edit: Just an update on my progress. I did some research and tried to get my program to work, but still no luck. I was able to get it to run, but it still only sets the root. My guess is I am either overwriting $a0 or not correctly setting the subtrees. I have to save $a0 before each recursion down build_tree, but no matter what, it either leads to accessing nonexistent memory or doesn't seem to do anything at all. At the very top, I experimented with having an s register saved on the stack dedicated to storing $a0 and doing a single load word to $a0 with the necessary offset when it came to going left or right. But I guess that's not right. Also, in the picture I meant for a 12 to be inside the root, not sure what I was thinking putting 3 in there because that makes no sense. So pretend that's a 12.

Comment: If you have a link I may be able to add the picture.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant the one when I add the image? https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF0qf.jpg Or that may work it does for me lol.

Comment: If you have your picture somewhere that I can view it maybe I could edit your question to include it.

Comment: Oh okay I uploaded it to imgur: https://imgur.com/a/vPQb30T. Thanks for doing that! :)